# IEEE standards name using uppercase and lowercase

Tags: networking

Why do some IEEE standards use uppercase for their name, such as 802.1Q while others use lowercase, such as 802.1s ?

Does any logic exist behind it, or it is a "random" decision for each IEEE standard, according to the working team ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are *not* RFCs, they are IEEE standards, which are very different things.

The uppercase on the letter indicates that the standard can be applied to all the IEEE LAN protocols. It doesn't mean that it is actually implemented by all the protocols, only that it is possible that all LAN protocols can use the standard. For example, 802.1Q is widely used in 802.3 (ethernet), but is not widely implemented by 802.11 (Wi-Fi).